# How to call the r function rnorm in C++

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Sorry I am a beginner but I am having trouble with this issue. I am just looking for the simplest way to call the rnorm function in R from C ++. I have looked into the rcpp package but even after reading all the tutorials I am stil very confused. I would appreciate someone walking me through the steps as someone who is experienced with programming but not the rcpp package.

Comment: I take it you have read http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i08/paper especially page 9....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You now get`R::rnorm()` as an interface to the *scalar* function from the R API (using a reasonably recent version of Rcpp) and there is of course the vectorised version of `rnorm` in Rcpp itself:

```
R> cppFunction('double scalarN(double m, double s) { return R::rnorm(m, s); }')
R> set.seed(42); scalarN(0,1);
[1] 1.37096
R> cppFunction('NumericVector vectorN(int N) { return rnorm(N); }')
R> set.seed(42); vectorN(3);
[1]  1.370958 -0.564698  0.363128
R>
```

Here we compiled one-line C++ functions on the fly using the `cppFunction` helper from the newer Rcpp Attributes addition.

Answer (score 1):

From this guide: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-quickref.pdf

It looks like you can just call it with

```
rnorm(20)
```

Are you looking for the normal distribution of random numbers from the R library?